# Panels to do a specific layout for one content type edit mode

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

How can i use panels to do a specific layout for a content type only for the add and edit form ?
I'm a newbie on panels but not on Drupal.I'm using panels 3 on D7.
will be great to give me examples or tutos ..

thanks

Comment: I added the page-manager tag, as that's the tag that should be on there. Leaving Panels on though, as people are more likely to search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page manager (which, technically isn't the same thing as Panels), manages the url `node/%` differently from `node/%/edit`.

When you to go `Pages`, you need to enable the node edit task, and make configuration to that page, not the node view one.